# How to define different value for same oozie workflow parameter in different shell actions?

Tags: shell, parameters, oozie

In my oozie job.properties file I have set a parameter called "jobname". I have a fork running three shell actions. I all the three shell actions I want to assign new value to the workflow property "jobname". How is it possible?

Comment: I have used capture-output option of a shell action to pass a parameter from one action to another. But that also can not be done in concurrent execution in your case. Might be you have to execute the shell action one after the other and try to pass the value. This might be just a try.

Comment: But it won't serve my purpose. All the shell actions should run in parallel as they are in fork. And if they execute sequentially then my parallelism is gone...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting three different parameters in job.properties(jobname1, jobname2, jobname3), which will be used by three shell actions. 
Another option is to use the String *EL functions in oozie* to manipulate the "jobname" value at runtime.

For example: Use **concat(${jobname}, "first")** function to append an identifier to the jobname which will differentiate each action's jobname.